# Induced Electric field in a dielectric medium and the force due to it

Tags: electric-fields, dielectric

I had a conceptual confusion regarding the electric field that is induced inside a dielectric medium. I'll paint you a picture in order to illustrate my confusion. Please feel free to point out any conceptual mistakes I make in the process of doing so and sorry for the upcoming wall of text:

The problem I am dealing with can be viewed as multiple charged conductors existing within a homogeneous dielectric medium. Since the conductors are charged, they will create an electric field (and hence an electrostatic force derived from Coloumb's Law) onthe other charged conductors.
Now take any one particular charged conductor. I want to calculate what the total force it will experience in such a system. Obviously one component is the Coloumb force from other conductors. The second I presume will be due to the additional electric fieldwhich is induced in the dielectric medium due to its interaction with the electric field between the charged conductors. What I'm also presuming is that the Maxwell's stress tensor will now depend on the induced Electric field, instead of the electric fieldbetween the conductors.
Since I want to calculate the force due to the induced electric field on one conductor, I was thinking of going about it by either of the following 2 ways:

1). The seemingly easier option -> I calculate the induced electric field, and then just multiply it with the charge on the second conductor in order to get the force (dimensionally it makes sense to just multiply the affected charge with the electric fieldit is experiencing, plus that's also how i calculate the Coloumb force)

2). The second option is to calculate the Maxwell Stress Tensor and then compute the forces on the conductor on the basis of the stresses. In this case, there is a slight ambiguity related to the area I need to use in order to get the forces.

For both the methods, I wil require the induced electric field ( im assuming I'll have to use the induced electric field in the Maxwell Stress Tensor instead of the electric field between the charged, if I'm wrong with this, please correct me).

So in summary, I wanted to ask how to compute the induced electric field, and if my reasoning and approach is sound?

Thanks in Advance!